# Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, xampp

I am getting the document saved with the user's information. Or sending document to email when I open email and click on link then I am getting error how to solve it.
**Error "Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed";**

**What to do solve this issue.**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Be Specific about when you are getting this error? @Amitabh kumar

Comment: When I am opening the link which came on Meltrap.

Comment: Sorry, @Amitabh Kumar. I did not get you there.

Comment: Can you share more details, like the code involved?

Answer (score 2):

Closures are PHP Code, which is not serializable by design, just like resources (open file pointers, database connections, ...).

You'll have to remove those things from your data structure before serializing it.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I tried to write to the session.
`request()->session()->put('url.intended', url($slug));` but $slug was null, so just wrapped it in an if and that seemed to resolve the issue

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).